# Jenkins does not getting the latest commit

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying to configure jenkins with github. Basically when there are no files in workspace (the first build) everything is going fine and jenkins fetches the latest changes. But when I trigger another build (after push into github) the latest change aren`t fetched.

Can you please give me some advice on this?
Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you see in your console output?

Answer (score 4):

Check the clock on the machine that runs jenkins. I experienced a similar issue where my build server was 2 minutes time difference off the source repository server, latest changes were not  picked up immediately but with delay.